# Ant Design components not loading on Next.js production server but work on development server

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, code-splitting, dynamic-import

I am working on a Next.js app where I am using Ant Design for the UI components. To decrease the initial load time of the app, I have used dynamic imports for the header. However, doing so causes a bug where some Ant Design packages (Menu and Input) won't load on the header when changing pages internally using Next.js Link component. The bug goes away when I refresh the page.

I have tried statically importing the header, and it resolves the issue. However, it increases the load time of the app.

What is the best way to solve this issue and decrease the initial load time of the app without encountering the bug?

[image: The issue]

Expected
[image: Expected output]

`const Header = dynamic(() => import('src/components/Header/Header'), { ssr: false, });`

I appreciate any help or insights on this issue. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone facing this issue, check ant design's CSS. It wasn't loading in my case.